# Firebase Cloud Messaging notification with curl getting MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing Android apps with firebase(ver.9.4.0).

When I sent FCM notifications using tokens as shown below, only some devices couldn't get the notification.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -d "{ \"data\": {\"url\":\"http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"type\":\"0\"}, \"priority\":\"high\",\"notification\": {\"body\": \"title\"}, \"registration_ids\":[\"APA91bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"]}"
```

Error message:

```
{"multicast_id":5831565775247505735,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

The tokens which couldn't send start from `APA91b`.

The tokens which could send start from `XXXXXXXXXXX:APA91b`.

Comment: The possible reasons for the error are [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the token into your database. Because when you uninstall the app or clear the data then token gets changed.

Comment: Thank you but the tokens are not old.
They are just created.

Comment: Check your key in console with the key which you are using, If it not work then try to regenerate the key in console.

Comment: I checked the key and the key was correct.
Even though some of tokens were OK but the others weren't.

Comment: Are you storing the tokens into database? If yes then check the token in Log and in database. put the length of tokens in database long so that it can be stored correctly.

Comment: I checked tokens in logs, my database and debug.
They are exactly same.
The token looks like 12 character missing when it fail.

Comment: copy the token and use directly into your fcm file for testing purpose.

Comment: what is the fcm file?

Comment: your php file in which you are writing your code for sending the notification.